# .htaccess check header and domain conditions as chain

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Sorry this might be an easy one.
I'd like to check if both matches. The value of my header and the HTTP_REFERER

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?alloweddomain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-SomeHeader} !somekey
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Otherwise I'd like to block the User.

The header check works nicely, and the documents are only served when it is correct. However the HTTP_REFERER seems to be ignored. The resources are even served when it is nor present. F.e with curl. How do I need to change the conditions that both must match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?alloweddomain.com [NC]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-SomeHeader} !somekey
> RewriteRule ^ - [F]
> ```

This is currently checking that both do **not** match. If the `Referer` header is not present, but `somekey` is passed then the request is *not* blocked.

You need an `OR` flag on the first *condition*. ie. If either do not match then block the request. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?alloweddomain.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-SomeHeader} !=somekey
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

You also need the `=` operator on the second *CondPattern* for an exact match, otherwise you are checking whether `somekey` exists anywhere in the passed header.

OR, reverse the logic:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http(s)?://(www\.)?alloweddomain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-SomeHeader} =somekey
RewriteRule ^ - [S=1]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

If both match then the following rule that blocks the request is skipped.

---

**UPDATE:**

> but a GET parameter, can you guide how I would do that? This is what I've tried `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} apikey!=somekey`

With the `RewriteCond` directive you are performing a (regex) string comparison. The value of the `QUERY_STRING` server variable (ie. `%{QUERY_STRING}`) is compared against the string/regex `apikey!=somekey`. This will never match since you should be checking for the "string" `apikey=somekey`. The `=` (or `!=`) is not a comparison operator, it's just part of the string. (Not to be confused with the `!` prefix operator on the *CondPattern* itself (as used above) that negates the whole expression.)

To check that the string "apikey=somekey" is not contained anywhere in the `QUERY_STRING` then use the *CondPattern* `!apikey=somekey`. However, this is potentially too broad, since (as mentioned) this is checking that the string is not *contained anywhere* in the `QUERY_STRING`. A query string of the form `fooapikey=somekeybar` would also be successful. You could instead perform an exact string comparison (as above). For example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !=apikey=somekey
```

That's OK if the query string can only consist of the `apikey` URL parameter and nothing else, but if you are potentially expecting other URL parameters on the same request, eg. `foo=1&apikey=somekey&bar=1` or `apikey=somekey` then you need to resort to a regex of the form:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)apikey=somekey($|&)
```

The *condition* is successful when the URL parameter `apikey=somekey` (exact string) is *not* contained anywhere in the query string.

Comment: @toni Almost, but not quite (the `!=` or `=` in the middle is not an operator, this is just part of the string to be matched). I've updated my answer.